# Playwright: expect.toHaveAttribute: Unsupported token "@xpath" while parsing selector

Tags: css-selectors, assert, playwright

In Playwright I created a script to verify the title using toHaveAttribute assertion for this element:

```
<title style="" xpath="1">Unient | Your Versatile Partner for Better Offshoring</title>
```

Here is my code:

```
    import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('Landing page', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://www.unient.biz/');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Accept All' }).click();
  const Title = page.locator("/html/head/title[@xpath='1']");
  await expect(Title).toHaveAttribute("title","Unient | Your Versatile Partner for Better Offshoring");
});
```

But there is an error and I am not really sure how to fix this:

```
expect.toHaveAttribute: Unsupported token "@xpath" while parsing selector "/html/head/title[@xpath='1']"
=========================== logs ===========================
expect.toHaveAttribute with timeout 5000ms
============================================================

  5 |   await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Accept All' }).click();
  6 |   const Title = page.locator("/html/head/title[@xpath='1']");
> 7 |   await expect(Title).toHaveAttribute("xpath","Unient | Your Versatile Partner for Better Offshoring");
    |                       ^
  8 | });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use ideally [toHaveTitle](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-pageassertions#page-assertions-to-have-title)

```
await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/.*titleTextORregularExpression/);
```

Reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-pageassertions#page-assertions-to-have-title

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received indicates that the selector you provided is not valid due to the unsupported attribute `@xpath`. Instead of using `@xpath`, you can use a more generic selector for the `title` element using the `textContent` property, like this:

```
const Title = page.locator("title");
await expect(Title).toHaveAttribute("textContent","Unient | Your Versatile Partner for Better Offshoring");
```

This code should correctly locate the `title` element on the page and verify its text content using the `toHaveAttribute` assertion.

Here's the updated script:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('Landing page', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://www.unient.biz/');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Accept All' }).click();
  const Title = page.locator("title");
  await expect(Title).toHaveAttribute("textContent","Unient | Your Versatile Partner for Better Offshoring");
});
```

For more information on the `toHaveAttribute` assertion in Playwright, you can refer to the official documentation: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#elementhandletohaveattributeattribute-value-options